# UITableViewCell imageView causes too much indention

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a subclassed `UITableViewCell` that I am setting the `imageView` for. I want to keep it at 60x60, so I set the `frame` and `bounds` in the `layoutSubviews` method of my subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(10,10,60,60);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,60,60);
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

}//end
```

This works great, until I have an image that goes outside of the bounds of the `imageView`:

[image]

Because of that, I make sure to set `clipsToBounds` to YES:

[image]

But as you can see it is still indenting the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` even though I don't think it should be.

**How can I fix this issue?**

Comment: have you tried setting text alignment if textLabel and detailTextLabel to right align?

Comment: It's redundant to set the bounds and frame like that. Setting the frame implicitly sets the bounds. Not that that makes a difference here.

Comment: I would recommend not using the built-in subviews (`imageView`, `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel`) if you're subclassing, because the base class will reposition them for you in undesirable ways. Just create and add your own image view and labels (either in `init` or `awakeFromNib`).

Comment: @warrenm Yeah, I figured I should just create my own `imageView` but just wanted to see if I was missing something easy doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of your `textLabel` in your `-layoutSubviews` implementation:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(10,10,60,60);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,60,60);
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    CGFloat x = 10.0 + 60.0 + 10.0; // Padding, image width, and padding.

    CGRect frame = self.textLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = x;
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = x;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;

} //end
```

You probably want to adjust the value of `x`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution, which I went with, was to not use the build in `imageView` but to roll my own. This worked much better.